# angular2 + systemjs + jspm + less

Tags: typescript, less, angular, jspm

I'm migrating our **Angular2** app from babel to jspm and **Systemjs** and I do not know how to nicely add **less** files to component-template.

*Till now it was compiled by Babel and managed by his config file*

I found this way, but I think that is not the proper way

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

import * as less from './signup.less!';


@Component({
  selector: 'app',  // <main></main>

  styles: [ less.toString() /* System.import('./signup.less!') */ ], 

  templateUrl : './app/signup/signup.html'

})
export class Signup {
.
.
. }
```

Maybe there is a way with `System.import(...)` The app is coded in TypeScript. And I have installed the `jspm-less-plugin@0.0.5`

EDIT: this solution doesn't work because the `less.toString()` add just `'[Object]'`.

Comment: It doesn't seem like that plugin supports loading just the compiled css text; it tries to inject it into directly the document and that won't work with Angular2.

Comment: The source for `plugin-text` is relatively simple (see https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-text/blob/master/text.js), so if you if you can figure out a way to turn a less source file into css (which I'm sure there are libraries for), you should be able to adapt it to work for this problem.